# How to set only apple logo image to sign in with apple button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

I am developing an app where i have provided three sign-in options like facebook, google and apple. and i need to set same designs for all three. my sign-in with apple button is rectangular and i want to know can i change design of that button and how. i need to make it circular with apple logo only and with not text. so how can i set apple logo image to **ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton**. i have read about apple designs on following link but nothing is mentioned about how to set image to button .
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/buttons-and-marks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your custom button as per [Apple Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/). You have to follow their guidelines to avoid review rejections.

You can download apple design resource from [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/)

**To add custom button in app:**

```
func appleCustomLoginButton() {
   //Sign in with app is only available from iOS 13 onwards
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let customAppleLoginBtn = UIButton()
        customAppleLoginBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        customAppleLoginBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "appleLogo"), for: .normal)
        customAppleLoginBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionHandleAppleSignin), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(customAppleLoginBtn)

        // Setup Layout Constraints to be in the center of the screen
        customAppleLoginBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            customAppleLoginBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            customAppleLoginBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            customAppleLoginBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            customAppleLoginBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            ])
    }
}

@objc func actionHandleAppleSignin() {

    //do something when button is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. If you have any further query please feel free to ask, Thank you.

```
     //1. setting apple logo
        let appleLogo = UIImage(systemName: "appleLogo.png")!
     //2. create a button
        let button = UIButton()
     //3. setImage with image name
        button.setImage(appleLogo, for: .normal)
     //4. Set image rounded.
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.height/2
     //5. Setting empty button text
        button.titleLabel?.text = ""
```

Comment: Please give some explanation why you think this is a correct solution. It may be very simple for you, but not for others.

Comment: Hey @koen did you tried my method. Because This is very simple way. I have written comment for understanding.

Comment: How can I modify the font size of the title or label

Comment: Do you mean Button text font?